# How to use streaming operator to get bit slice from an array

Tags: system-verilog

I have the following code

```
logic [99:0] a[10]; // in this only the LSB 10 bits are relevant 
logic [49:0] b;
```

I want to take the useful bits of `a` and assign it to `b`

I tried streaming operator but could not get it to work

```
b = { << 10 {a[0:5]}}; // EDIT: Correcting typo
```

Is it possible to do this? I went over the SV LRM and streaming operator but could not grasp it in its entirety.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the streaming operator or a bit-stream cast to operate on a non-contiguous set of bits. You can use a `foreach` loop.

```
foreach (a[ii]) b[ii*5+:5] = a[ii][5:0];
```

You will have to fiddle with this as your text description did not match up with the pseudo code you tried to write.